# Kalman Filtering the Vasicek Model, are there different Kalman Filters for the same application?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, maximum-likelihood, kalman-filter, stochastic-programming

While studying parameter estimation in affine term structure models, I stumbeled across two papers.

1. Affine Term-Structure Models: Theory and Implementation by David Bolder (2001)
   https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4744752_Affine_Term-Structure_Models_Theory_and_Implementation
2. Calibration of the Vasicek Model of Interest rates Using Bicriteria Optimization by Jasurkova and Stehlikova (2020)
   http://www.iam.fmph.uniba.sk/amuc/ojs/index.php/algoritmy/article/view/1585

In both papers, a Kalman filter is implemented for the Vasicek model. In Bolder's work, for a 3-factor Vasicek model, and in Jasurkova and Stehlikova's work, a 1-factor Vasicek model. However, in my opinion, both methods should be independent of the number of factors. But upon closer inspection, there are a few differences, in addition to some different writing styles. When both present the necessary steps for implementing the Kalman filter, there are some discrepancies:

-In the first and second step, everythink agrees in both papers.
When moving to the third step, however, things differ: Bolder writes in equation (74) the following:

$var[y_{t_i} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t_{i}}] = (I-K_{t_i}H)var[y_{t_i} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t_{i-1}}]$

whereas Jasurkova and Stehlikova state that: (page 214)

$Var[r_{t_i} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t_{i}}] = (I-K_{t_i}H)Var[R_{t_i} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t_{i-1}}]$

the small $y$ in Bolder's work corresponds to the small $r$, which are in both cases the short rates. And for the bond rates Bolder writes $z_{t_i}$ corresponding to $R_{t_i}$ in the work from Jasurkova and Stehlikova.

Proceeding to step 4, when the state vector/variable is updated things continue to differ:

Bolder writes:

$\mathbb{E}[y_{t_{i+1}} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t_{i}}] = C + F\mathbb{E}[y_{t_{i}} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t_{i}}]$

In  the other paper it is written that:

$\mathbb{E}[r_{t_{i+1}} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t_{i+1}}] = C + F\mathbb{E}[r_{t_{i}} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t_{i}}]$

and for the conditional variance:

$var[y_{t_{i+1}} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t_{i}}] = var[y_{t_{i}} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t_{i-1}}]-Fvar[y_{t_{i}} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t_{i}}]F^T + Q$

$Var[r_{t_{i+1}} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t_{i}}] = FVar[r_{t_{i}} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t_{i}}]F^T + Q$

Additionally, the construction of the Likelihood function differs, beside the fact that Bolder uses the log-likelihood function:

Log-likelihood function by Bolder (equation (77)):

$l(\theta) = - \frac{nNln(2\pi)}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^N [ln(det(var[y_{t_{i}} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t_{i-1}}])) + \zeta_{t_i}^{T}(var[y_{t_{i}} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t_{i-1}}]^{-1}\zeta_{t_i}]$

The Likelihood function by Jasurkova and Stehlikova:

$\mathcal{L}(\kappa,\theta,\sigma,\lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{(2 \pi )^{\frac{m}{2}} \vert Var[R_{t_i} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t_{i-1}}] \vert ^{\frac{1}{2}} } e^{-\frac{1}{2} \zeta_{t_i}^{T}Var[R_{t_i} \vert \mathcal{F}_{t_{i-1}}]^{-1}\zeta_{t_i}}$

In total, these differences should result in a completely different likelihood function (beside the log) and therefore also in a different output of the Kalman filter. My question now is whether there is a mistake in one of the papers?
Or are there different Kalman filters that can explain these differences?

Comment: Hi: I don't have time to go through the equations but there are two versions of the kalman filter that are equivalent but the updating equations will be totally different. Let me see if I can find the answer I sent on dsp.stackexchange a long time ago. I also can't guarantee that that's what is going on in the above but it probably is. Let me look for my answer there. Actually, I'm running late for an appointment. Could you go to dsp.stackexchange and then under users look for my name. The title of the answer should make it obvious.

Comment: I found it. I'm in a rush but,  and, like I said, I don't have time to go through it to confirm but the explanation at the link here is probably what's causing the differences that you see. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/58221/kalman-filter-order-of-update-step/58231#58231. You'd need to go through it carefully to make sure that this is the case.